# Layout with liquid-fixed-liquid design...Can't seem to get it right

Tags: css, liquid-layout

I know I should know how to do this, but for all of my searching on SO and the internet, it's evading me. A friend wants a page with a fixed width centered wrapper, 990px wide. Left and right will have no content, but he wants the header and footer to stretch off the ends of the page like a liquid layout. I never build sites like this so I'm stuck, I only do fixed width centered wrappers.

I want to accomplish this with CSS over tables, that's his preference.

The header isn't straight black, it's a thin .png that is repeated as a BG image.

The footer is a solid BG color.

Page is currently set up with the proper header and footer contained in the center wrapper but nothing is stretching off to the left and right.

Page link: http://www.jalvisualmedia.com/testsite/mystique/private_label.php

If I'm omitting anything that would be helpful, please let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try putting the #wrapperTop and #footer ids outside of the fixed width center wrapper and set their width to 100%.

Comment: That works, EXCEPT the header image and navbar shift to the left. and they want to be in the center of th epage that is fixed. See: http://www.jalvisualmedia.com/testsite/mystique/products.php as reference. Thank you though!

Comment: UPDATE: I fixed the problem mentioned above by changing the margin on the #navbar and #header divs to `margin:0 25% 0 25%;` and it worked, so thank you @smang. Now to try it on the footer.

Comment: UPDATE: I did the same treatment with the footer, though the navbar and copyright notice were still shifting to the left I added the same 25% left margin to the div containing the footer info and Voila! Thank you @smang so much! My trouble in trying this previously was that I wasn't applying the left margin of 25% to the elemants that I wanted to center. Once I did that, BINGO! Thank you!!!

Comment: Glad to hear you got it working. If you are looking to center the text, you can also use position: relative and text-align: center instead of adding the margins.

Comment: good tip. However, as you'll see from the links, it's not that I wanted them centered in the center wrapper, but simply located in the center wrapper, off to the left a bit. Either way, your suggestion sparked an intuituve thread in my tired brain that got the results I was looking for. Again, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
#wrapperTop{
    width: 100%;
    height: 162px;
    margin: 0;
}

#navbar {
    height: 40px;
    width: 990px;
    margin: auto;
    background-image: url(../graphics/bg_top.png);
}

#header {
    height: 120px;
    width: 990px;
    margin: auto;
}

#imageSlice {
    width: 990px;
    height: 95px;
    background-color: white;
    margin: auto;
}​

#footer {
    width: 100%;
    height: 145px;
    margin: 0;
    background-image: url(../graphics/bg_bottom.png);
}

#navBox {
    width: 600px;
    height: 75px;
    margin: auto;
}
```

​

Comment: @ so geek, many thanks! I'll give it a whirl, as I continue to tweak the pages. Smang's tips helped me get the desired results, but I'll certainly try yours as well. Many thanks!